# Convert object to a string c# xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, tostring

I want to convert a label value (Object) to a string variable but I get an empty string.

Here is the code.

```
var label = new Label
            {

            };
            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Link");
            string url = label.GetValue(Label.TextProperty).toString();
```

I want to use the content of the label as a string.

If I don't convert it the url in the label it's ok but when I convert it I get an empty string as result. Any help? How can I convert this to a string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried label.Text?

Comment: If you mean "string url = label.text" then yes I've tried but I get a null result.

Comment: if you're using databinding then you should get the value from the bound property that is populating the label, not the label itself.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that, can you help me any further?

Comment: you are binding your Label to the "Link" property of some object.  So rather than get the value of the Label, you really should just get the Link property of whatever object you're bound to.

Comment: I tried to get the Link value by putting it in the Label value. I don't know what code should I use to get a Binding value directly.

Comment: do you have an object with a Link property?  What is the name of that object?

Comment: The object name is Announcement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a very easy solution as @hichame.yessou already mentioned on the first comment.

I was passing data into a label by XAML

```
<Label Text="{Binding Link}" x:Name="linkLabel" IsVisible="False" />
```

But I put the "x:name" property in order to handle the label from the xaml.cs file.

Well then all was easy..

```
string url = linkLabel.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Label` text implicitely, but I have a feeling that's not what you're trying to do.

If you want to bind to a `Link` property from a ViewModel, you probably just forgot to set the `BindingContext` for your `Label`.

```
        var label = new Label
        {
            Text = "Set implicitely"
        };

        string url = label.GetValue(Label.TextProperty).ToString(); // Set implicitely

        MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {
            Link = "Set through binding"
        };

        label.BindingContext = viewModel;
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Link");

        string url2 = label.GetValue(Label.TextProperty).ToString(); // Set through binding
```

Comment: I just want to get the value of the "Link" property and I tried to do this by inserting in a label. But I can't get the value of the label into a string variable either directly or from the label.

Comment: You'll have to give more information as this code inserted in the constructor of `MainPage` class of an empty Xamarin Forms project does return a valid string.

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit strange. Well there is a class Called Announcement and a property of this class is the "Link" property. I pass this "Link" value from Page1 to Page2 by the xaml file, but I want to pass it by the xaml.cs file but I don't know how to pass it directly so I created a new label, I put the "Link" TextProperty into the label and tried to get it that way. The fact is that the label content is displayed properly but when I convert it to string it returns an empty string. I hope I helped you! Otherwise I will answer the code from my project as it is with the proper comments.